# Access Form: turn text-box green if >= another text-box (using conditional formatting)

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting

On an MS Access form, I have two textboxes, `txtbox1` and `txtbox2`. I'm not sure how to use conditional formatting correctly with this situation. I'm trying to make `txtbox1` turn green if it's greater than or equal to `txtbox2`.

**Example 1**: `txtbox2` = $100 and txtbox1 = $90. So `txtbox1` stays black.
**Example 2**: `txtbox2` = $100 and txtbox1 = $120. So `txtbox1` changes to green.

I've tried many things but it seems like a simple syntax thing im not getting. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please expand on what you've tried? Which "syntax thing" are you stuck on? This would need to be done with a line or two of VBA in the Change event for the textbox(es). Access has no "Conditional Formatting" like Excel does (unless you're working on an Access Web application?).

Answer (score 0):

In design view of your form, select `txtbox1` and open the Conditional Fomratting Rules Manager (on the *Format* tab). Create a new rule for the current value. Configure the rule to format cells where the **Field value** is **greater than or equal** the value of `txtbox2` (use the Expression Builder to select that TextBox). Beneath that formatting rule, specify the format by selecting a green fill color.